# A simple math operations with MYSQL (phpMyAdmin-console)

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to make this simple math operation starting from a column value called "prezzo_storico" ...

```
UPDATE `products` 
SET `prezzo_perizia` = (ROUND(`prezzo_storico` * 100/34.5))+2) 
WHERE `id_fallimento` = 192
```

But some how the operation is not going on.
Can anyone help me to understand why?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query

```
UPDATE `products` 
SET `prezzo_perizia` = ROUND(`prezzo_storico` * 100/34.5)+2
WHERE `id_fallimento` = 192
```